# how to match only once occurrence of a double space of a line?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

**line A**

```
foo bar  bar foo  bar foo
```

**line B**

```
foo bar  bar foo
```

In **line A**, there are multiple occurrence of double space.

I only want to match lines like **line B** which has only once double space occurrence.

I tried

```
^.*\s{2}.*$
```

but it will match both.

How may I have the desired output? Thank you.

Comment: Why even use regex for this? Doesn't seem like the best option. Just find the number of occurrences of two consecutive space characters in the string. Or if you want to prevent counting more than two spaces, you could use regex and count the number of `(?<![ ]{2})[ ]{2}(?![ ]{2})` matches.

Comment: @41686d6564 i had a stream of string data with this pattern, a line with only once occurrence of double space means it is a double column, but with more than once occurrence of double space is unclassified. so I need to distinguish between these two cases.

Comment: Use the pattern in my previous comment. It will match _all_ the two consecutive space characters that are not immediately preceded or followed by other space characters (i.e., exactly two). Now, count the number of matches in each line and you've got your solution (i.e., you expect only one match, no more and no less). Good luck!

Comment: @41686d6564, there are many questions posted with a regex tag where there may be non-regex solutions that are arguably better in some sense. Some of those questions merely reflect a desire by the asker to improve their understanding of some features of regular expressions, with no claim that use of a regex would be the preferred approach to the given problem. By all means offer non-regex solutions to questions having regex tags (except where question states that a regex must be used), but recognize that the asker may have good reasons for wanting a regex solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to match strings that contain no more than one string of two or more spaces between words you could use following regular expression.

```
r'^(?!(?:.*(?<! ) {2,}(?! )){2})'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/KEhZxh/2/)

Note that this expression matches

```
abc    de fgh
```

where there are four spaces between `'c'` and `'d'`.

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^
(?!           : begin negative lookahead
  (?:         : begin non-capture group
    .*        : match 0+ characters other than line terminators
    (?<!      : begin negative lookbehind
      [ ]{2,} : match 2+ spaces
      (?! )   : negative lookahead asserts match is not followed by a space
    )         : end negative lookbehind
  )           : end non-capture group
  {2}         : execute non-capture group twice
)             : end negative lookahead
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
^(?!.*[ \t]{2,}.*[ \t]{2,})

# Negative look ahead assertion that states 'only start the match 
# on this line IF there are NOT 2 (or potentially more) breaks with
# two (or potentially more) of tabs or spaces'.
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/Zplyoo/2/)

If you want to require ONE double space in the line but not more:

```
^(?=.*[ \t]{2,})(?!.*[ \t]{2,}.*[ \t]{2,})

# Positive look ahead that states 'only start this match if there is 
# at least one break with two tabs or spaces'

# BUT

# Negative look ahead assertion that states 'only start the match 
# on this line IF there are NOT 2 (or potentially more) breaks with
# two (or potentially more) of tabs or spaces'.
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Zplyoo/3/)

If you want to limit to only two spaces (not tabs and not more than 2 spaces):

```
^(?=.*[ ]{2})(?!.*[ ]{2}.*[ ]{2})
# Same as above but remove the tabs as part of the assertion
```

[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/Zplyoo/4/)

Note: In your regex you have `\s` as the class for a space. That also matches `[\r\n\t\f\v ]` so both horizontal and vertical space characters.

Note 2:
You can do this without a regex as well (assuming you only want lines that have 1 and only 1 double space in them):

```
txt='''\
line A

foo bar  bar foo  bar foo
line B

foo bar  bar foo'''

>>> [line for line in txt.splitlines() if len(line.split('  '))==2]
['foo bar  bar foo']
```

Comment: thanks, it works. would you please explain why does it need an extra `[ ]{2}` at the end? i cannot understand the logic here..

Answer (score 1):

You can get the match without lookarounds by starting the match with 1+ non whitespace chars.

Then optionally repeat a single whitespace char followed by non whitespace chars before and after matching a double whitespace char.

The negated character class `[^\S\r\n]` will match any whitespace chars except a newline or carriage return. If you want to allow matching newlines as well, you could use `\s`

```
^\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]\S+)*[^\S\r\n]{2}(?:\S+[^\S\r\n])*\S+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\S\r\n]\S+` Match a whitespace char without a newline
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `[^\S\r\n]{2}` Match the 2 whitespace chars without a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\S+[^\S\r\n]` Match 1+ non whitespace chars followed by a whitespace char without a newline
- `)*` Close group a and repeat 1+ times
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3hIzpL/1/)